# Polymer 2 Conditional Attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, polymer

I tried finding information on conditional attributes for Polymer 2, but I could only find stuff on Polymer 1. Does anyone know to do it ?

Comment: what do you mean by "conditional attributes"? that you want them to be missing in some cases? in that case the value you bind to (either a method call or a property) should evaluate to false..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Polymer 1.0, the syntax for attribute binding was:

```
<x-foo attr?="{{boolean-expression}}">
```

In Polymer 2.0, the [syntax changed](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#anatomy-of-a-data-binding) from `?=` to `$=`:

```
<x-foo attr$="{{boolean-expression}}">
```

```js
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', () => {
  class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'x-foo'; }
    
    static get properties() {
      return {
        checked: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false
        }
      };
    }
    
    _toggleCheck() {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
  }
  customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <button on-click="_toggleCheck">Toggle check</button>
      <input type="checkbox" checked$="{{checked}}">
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this? [Polymer attribute binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding)

Some extra info on @tony19 answer would be the binding, `{{value}}` is for two-way binding and `[[value]]` is for one-way binding. An interesting thing is that `{{value}}` would actually convert to one-way binding automatically if two-way data binding can't be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dom-if:
[Polymer 2.0 dom-if](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.DomIf)

Or you can use a computed method
[Observers and computed properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.DomIf)

On a element in a dom-repeat for example:

```
<my-element class$="is-active-[[_isActive(item.active)]]"></my-element>

_isActive(active) {
    return active ? true : false;
}
```